# Looking for a function that gives value of 0 to 1 with input of 0 to 1

Tags: functions

I am looking for a function that has three variables and returns a value in $(0, 1)$ with one input variable in $(0, 1)$ and other variable of arbitrary values. The description of the function is depicted on the figure below. The return variable of the function is $a,$ and $b$ and $c$ are the input.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGiPl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

$$
a   = b^{1/c} .
$$

**Edit** in a response to comments.

I found constants $r$ and $s$ such that
$$
a   = rb^{s/c}  
$$
had value $c$ at $b = 1-c$ (on the diagonal) and slope $1$ there, then reflected that function over the diagonal to find the values between $1-c$ and $1$. Here's the formula:
$$
a    = 
c \left( \frac{b}{1-c} \right)^{(1-c)/c} \text{ when }
   0 \le a \le 1-c 
$$
and
$$
a = 1 - (1-c) 
\left( \frac{1-b}{c} \right)^{c/(1-c)}
 \text{ when }  1-c \le a \le 1
$$

Here's the picture, with $c = 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1$.

[image]

Comment: The answer function works. Now this function gives not symmetric values with lower values of c (lower than -5th power of ten). But how to make this function more hyperbolic to value of b=1.0?

Comment: I don't  know what your "not symmetric" and "more hyperbolic"  comments mean.  You could [edit] the question to include a picture of this function  overlaid somehow with a sketch of what you might prefer. It's easy to graph this one in a spreadsheet.

Comment: I just added some explanations on the figure (new figure) attached to the question. The peak or corner of the function should be overlaid with diagonal line from b=1 to a=1. The function a=b^(1/c) looks different that the function I need.

Comment: OK it looks as if you would like more symmetry about the diagonal of the square. I will think about that and edit my answer - probably not right away.